# Modify variable in django template by rendering middle of variable

Tags: python, django, split, django-templates

i have variable `key.links.self` (from json output) in template which is an URL:

```
https://ahostnamea.net:666/api/v1/
```

Now what i would like to do is render in template only `ahostnamea` from this variable.

I know it is possible to cut letters but when first letters always have same count (`https://` = 8 letters), the rest is not that simple and it gets different.


Is there any way to split/cut string from `/` to `.` ? Or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pattern with a capturing group and a negated character class `[^.]+` matching any char except a dot.

```
https?://([^.]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qkFB28/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Bnuiae)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"https?://([^.]+)"
test_str = "https://ahostnamea.net:666/api/v1/"
matches = re.search(regex, test_str)

if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
```

Result

```
ahostnamea
```

**Edit**

As suggested you could also use [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to get the hostname.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
o = urlparse("https://ahostnamea.net:666/api/v1/")
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Fvw0ja)

The you could get the first part by for example splitting on a dot:

```
s = o.hostname.split('.', 1)[0]
print(s)
```

Result

```
ahostnamea
```

Comment: this! registered this code (with little modification) as custom tag template and it wokred like a charm! thanks!

Comment: Why use a regexp when [all you need is already in the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have added an update using urlparse.

Comment: @Thefourthbird "Why downvote a working answer?" => because "working" doesn't mean "good" (or in this case "pythonic"). Using regexps when there's a more appropriate solution is considered bad style in Python.

Comment: @Thefourthbird and since you added the pythonic solution, I undownvoted your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A proper solution would be `{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}`

Comment: problem is that hostname has not always same number of characters